# trying to build a PortMidi example in Mingw

Tags: linker, mingw, midi, .a, .lib

Im trying to build a PortMidi example in Mingw but it depends on two libraries portmidi and winmm, I recompiled portmidi to get a portimidi.a but Im getting errors of missing code.

**Is posible to link winmm to mingw, and I have to use ".a" or ".lib" libraries?**

Im using this command to compile the source:

```
g++ -o prg latency.c -IHeaders -LLib -lportmidi -lwinmm
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I used this command to compile the example "gcc -o prg latency.c -IHeaders -lportmidi -lwinmm" and copy portmidi to lib folder in mingw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need winmm.a to build latency.c

you need
`libpmjni.dll.a` , `libportmidi.dll.a` or
`libportmidi_s.a`

To build portmidi wit CMake takes 5 minutes.

- portmidi source :    c:/src/portmidi217/
- portmidi build  :    c:/minGW/portmidi

Then you can compile it with the following command.

```
gcc.exe  -c -g -I/c/src/portmidi217/pm_common -I/c/src/portmidi217/porttime -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/latency.o.d -o build/Debug/latency.o latency.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug
gcc.exe  -o dist/Debug/latency build/Debug/latency.o -L/c/minGW/portmidi -lpmjni.dll -lportmidi.dll
```

---

---

**Building portmidi with CMake**

- Download or use Cmake
- in c:\cmake\bin folder double click `cmake-gui.exe`

unzip portmidi to the folder `c:\minGW\src\portmidi217` you can see in the next image
(replace all `T:\` with `C:\` of course)

[image]

press configure

[image]

settings as described --> click next

[image]

settings as described --> click ok

[image]

there a errors so click configure again

[image]

next looks better click configure again

[image]

settings as described Release or Debug
maybe it worked without `c:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe`
click configure again

[image]

looks good  --> click `Generate`

[image]

cd to your just builded `c:\minGW\portmidi`

[image]

open windows command type make

[image]

it takes a short time to build

[image]

there they are : `.a and .dll`

[image]

- copy all `.a` to `c:\minGW\lib`
- copy all `.dll` to `c:\minGW\bin`
- copy from `C:\minGW\src\portmidi217\pm_common` and `C:\minGW\src\portmidi217\porttime`
  all .h  to the folder where your `latency.c` is.

Then you can `latency.c` compile as described above, you just need to adjust the paths.

Comment: Thanks but libpmjni.dll.a uses java and I'm Trying to build it completely in c++ that's why I need to link winmm. I found that winmm exists as libwinmm.a in mingw's lib files but I tried to link it with -llibwinmm command with no success. Please help me.

Comment: I build it completely in C++ winmm is automatic linked to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\winmm.dll` it's a dll by system ! have you build portmidi with cmake to create the makefiles done in 5 minutes and compile with gcc `latency.c` in 1 minute it's very easy.

Comment: Can you help me with the command or cmake file please, Im having problems with cmake

Comment: Wow!! really thanks for your effort aswering my question, I wish some day I could help you..... Really thanks let me know if you need something

Comment: No now Im getting this "Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)" I already installed the jdk why is this?